# Why does this linear map from a definition of two polynomials' resultant involve two other polynomials?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Good afternoon stackexchangers.. I'm looking for more help with resultants of two polynomial functions.

[In this wiki page on resultants](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1XpW.png) I'm not understanding why the linear map $\varphi(P,Q) = AQ+BP$ is represented by the Sylvester matrix of $A$ and $B$. According to that definition, I've got to use a polynomial $P$ from the vector space of polynomials less than the degree of $B$ and a polynomial $Q$ from the vector space of polynomials of degree less than $A$ but I don't see  how the $P$ and $Q$ can be any polynomial from those spaces and still be represented by the same matrix.

[This page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/muXfX.png) also shows the matrix with just entries from the coefficients of what would be $A$ and $B$.

Here is [a computation I wrote of the matrix from two polynomials](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6QFz.jpg) and a [discriminant computation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFit6.jpg).

Comment: The *determinant* of the Sylvester matrix is a linear combination of $A$ and $B$, with the coefficients of the linear combination being the polynomials $P$ and $Q$ (and I think you want degree of $P$ less than degree of $A$, and degree of $Q$ less than degree of $B$).

Comment: I attached some work, but I didn't figure out how the determinant involves those polynomials or how they fix the columns or rows of the matrix.

Comment: From linear algbera you should remember that a matrix represents *a linear transformation between two vector spaces with respect to chosen bases*. Here $P$ comes from a space $P_n$ of polynomials of bounded degree, $Q$ from another space $P_m$ of bounded degree, so $(P,Q)$ comes from the direct sum $P_n\oplus P_m$. Then $\phi(P,Q)$ comes from the space of polynomials $P_{n+m}$. For all relevant $\ell$ the space $P_\ell$ has a basis $\{1,x,x^2,\ldots,x^{\ell-1}\}$, and you get a basis for the direct sum in the usual way. The rest then follows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're a bit confused here. The Sylvester matrix $S$ is the matrix that represents the map $(P,Q)\mapsto AQ+BP$. That is, if you give me two polynomials $P,Q$ then I can determine $AQ+BP$ by applying the matrix $S$ to the vector of coefficients of $P$ and $Q$. (There's nothing to do with the matrix representing $P$ and/or $Q$.)

Here's an example so you can better see what "representing the map $(P,Q)\mapsto AQ+BP$" means: if $A=x^3+x+1$ and $B=3x^2+2x+1$, then $$S = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 3 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 3 & 2 & 1 & 0 \\  0 & 0 & 3 & 2 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$ so if we have polynomials $Q=ax+b$ in $\mathcal{P}_{<\deg B}$ and $P=cx^2+dx+e$ in $\mathcal{P}_{<\deg A}$ then $$\begin{pmatrix} a \\ b \\ c \\ d \\ e \end{pmatrix}^T\cdot\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 3 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 3 & 2 & 1 & 0 \\  0 & 0 & 3 & 2 & 1 \end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix} a+3c \\ b+2c+3d \\ a+c+2d+3e \\ a+b+d+2e \\ b+e \end{pmatrix}^T$$ which exactly matches what we get from computing $AQ+BP$: $$(a+3c)x^4+(b+2c+3d)x^3+(a+c+2d+3e)x^2+(a+b+d+2e)x+(b+e).$$

Comment: 1) you can't do $5\times1$ matrix times $5\times5$ matrix – you have to take the transpose of that first matrix to get the product you have written. 2) what would you do if, say, $P$ had degree one? Something should be said about how you get a five-entry vector in that case.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I've added some transposes - you're right, I was a little sloppy there. As for what happens when $P$ has degree one, you just set $c=0$. $P$ is chosen from the space of polynomials of degree less than $\deg A$, so the written form is general.

Comment: Note that OP has (incorrectly) asked for $P$ to have degree less than $B$, and $Q$ to have degree less than $A$.